# Find columns with all missing values

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I am writing a function, which needs a check on whether (and which!) column (variable) has all missing values (`NA`, `<NA>`). The following is fragment of the function:

```
test1 <- data.frame (matrix(c(1,2,3,NA,2,3,NA,NA,2), 3,3))
test2 <- data.frame (matrix(c(1,2,3,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,2), 3,3))

na.test <-  function (data) {
  if (colSums(!is.na(data) == 0)){
      stop ("The some variable in the dataset has all missing value,
     remove the column to proceed")
      }
      }
na.test (test1)

Warning message:
In if (colSums(!is.na(data) == 0)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

**Q1:** Why is the above error and any fixes ?

**Q2:** Is there any way to find which of columns have all `NA`, for example output the list (name of variable or column number)?

Comment: I feel like this must have been answered before: something like `names(data)[lapply(data,function(x) all(is.na(x)))]`

Comment: Your parentheses are wrong. Write `colSums(!is.na(data)) == 0` instead of `colSums(!is.na(data) == 0)`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is easy enough to with `sapply` and a small anonymous function:

```
sapply(test1, function(x)all(is.na(x)))
   X1    X2    X3 
FALSE FALSE FALSE 

sapply(test2, function(x)all(is.na(x)))
   X1    X2    X3 
FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

And inside a function:

```
na.test <-  function (x) {
  w <- sapply(x, function(x)all(is.na(x)))
  if (any(w)) {
    stop(paste("All NA in columns", paste(which(w), collapse=", ")))
  }
}

na.test(test1)

na.test(test2)
Error in na.test(test2) : All NA in columns 2
```

Comment: thanks, I intention here to put as part of function, so that the function stop if there are any TRUE...which is important for me as I have big dataset with > 50000 variables

Comment: You may also be able to reduce the number of computations by noting that a columns comprised of only `NA` will be of `class` `logical`. Further, if you don't expect any other logical columns then this gives you the NA columns.

Comment: @James: that might be fragile. There are 'classed' versions of `NA`, such as `NA_integer_`, which show up as `NA` but are not logical.  It might depend on where the `NA`s came from ...

Comment: Is it me, or will this solution only return "TRUE" when ALL elements of the column are NA, rather than the initial request (that it return true if ANY element was NA)? I just tried it on a data.frame that has two known rows with NAs in them, and got a return set telling me that there were no NAs in any column.

Comment: @GT. Yes, that was the question as posed.  If you want to return TRUE if one or more values are missing, use `any()` instead of `all()`.

Answer (score 8):

To find the columns with all values missing

```
 allmisscols <- apply(dataset,2, function(x)all(is.na(x)));  
 colswithallmiss <-names(allmisscols[allmisscols>0]);    
 print("the columns with all values missing");    
 print(colswithallmiss);
```

Answer (score 8):

In dplyr

```
ColNums_NotAllMissing <- function(df){ # helper function
  as.vector(which(colSums(is.na(df)) != nrow(df)))
}

df %>%
select(ColNums_NotAllMissing(.))

example:
x <- data.frame(x = c(NA, NA, NA), y = c(1, 2, NA), z = c(5, 6, 7))

x %>%
select(ColNums_NotAllMissing(.))
```

or, the other way around

```
Cols_AllMissing <- function(df){ # helper function
  as.vector(which(colSums(is.na(df)) == nrow(df)))
}


x %>%
  select(-Cols_AllMissing(.))
```

Answer (score 6):

This one will generate the column names that are full of NAs:

```
library(purrr)
df %>% keep(~all(is.na(.x))) %>% names
```

Answer (score 4):

To test whether columns have all missing values:

```
apply(test1,2,function(x) {all(is.na(x))})
```

To get which columns have all missing values:

```
  test1.nona <- test1[ , colSums(is.na(test1)) == 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

dplyr approach to finding the number of NAs for each column:

```
df %>% 
  summarise_all((funs(sum(is.na(.)))))
```

Comment: the updated method is now `df %>% summarise_all((~ sum(is.na(.))))`

Answer (score 2):

Variant dplyr approach:

```
dataframe %>% select_if(function(x) all(is.na(x))) %>% colnames()
```

Comment: Hat tip: https://sebastiansauer.github.io/NAs-with-dplyr/

Answer (score 0):

The following command gives you a nice table with the columns that have NA values:

```
sapply(dataframe, function(x)all(any(is.na(x))))
```

It's an improvement for the first answer you got, which doesn't work properly from some cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
sapply(b,function(X) sum(is.na(X))
```

This will give you the count of na in each column of the dataset and also will give 0 if there is no na present in the column

Comment: ```sapply(b,function(X) sum(is.na(X)))```