# Using is.na in R to get Column Names that Contain NA Values

Tags: r, missing-data, na

Given the example data set below:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix( c(1, 2, 3, NA, 5, NA, 
                              7, NA, 9, 10, NA, NA), nrow=2, ncol=6))

names(df) <- c(  "varA", "varB", "varC", "varD", "varE", "varF")

print(df)

  varA varB varC varD varE varF
1    1    3    5    7    9   NA
2    2   NA   NA   NA   10   NA
```

I'd like to be able to use kmeans(...) on data sets without having to manually check or delete variables that contain NA **anywhere** within the variable. While I'm asking right now for kmeans(...) I'll be using a similar process for other things, so a kmeans(...) specific answer won't totally answer my question.

The manual version of what I'd like is:

```
kmeans_model <- kmeans(df[, -c(2:4, 6)], 10)
```

And the pseudo-code would be:

```
kmeans_model <- kmeans(df[, -c(colnames(is.na(df)))], 10)
```

Also, I don't want to delete the data from df.  Thanks in advance.

(Obviously kmeans(...) wouldn't work on this example data set but I can't recreate the real data set)

Comment: A very nearly duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11330138/324364

Comment: Probably `df[, which(!sapply(df, function(col) sum(!is.na(col)) > 0))]`

Comment: @lukeA Using `any()` might be easier to read and slightly shorter. (Could be slightly slower, though, I'd have to check.)

Comment: @joran I checked and chose `sum` because of that. ;)

Comment: @lukeA Well, there you go! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two options without `sapply`:

```
kmeans_model <- kmeans(df[, !colSums(is.na(df))], 10)
```

Or

```
kmeans_model <- kmeans(df[, colSums(is.na(df)) == 0], 10)
```

#### Explanation:

`colSums(is.na(df))` counts the number of NAs per column, resulting in:

```
colSums(is.na(df))
#varA varB varC varD varE varF 
#   0    1    1    1    0    2
```

And then

```
colSums(is.na(df)) == 0     # converts to logical TRUE/FALSE
#varA  varB  varC  varD  varE  varF 
#TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

is the same as

```
!colSums(is.na(df))
#varA  varB  varC  varD  varE  varF 
#TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Both methods can be used to subset only those columns where the logical value is TRUE

Answer (score 2):

This is the generic approach that I use for listing column names and their count of NAs:

```
sort(colSums(is.na(df)> 0), decreasing = T)
```

If you want to use sapply, you can refer this code snippet as well:

```
flights_NA_cols <- sapply(flights, function(x) sum(is.na(x))) 
flights_NA_cols[flights_NA_cols>0]
```