# Viewing all column names with any NA in R

Tags: r, sapply

I need to get the name of the columns that have at least 1 NA.

```
df<-data.frame(a=1:3,b=c(NA,8,6), c=c('t',NA,7))
```

I need to get "b, c".

I found [this code:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330138/finding-columns-with-all-missing-values-in-r)

> ```
> sapply(df, function(x) any(is.na(x)))
> ```

But I need only the variables that have any NA.

I tried this:

```
sapply(df, function(x) colnames(df[,any(is.na(x))]))
```

But I get all the column names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another acrobatic solution (just for fun) :

```
colnames(df)[!complete.cases(t(df))]
[1] "b" "c"
```

The idea is : Getting the columns of A that have at least 1 NA is equivalent to get the rows that have at least NA for t(A). 
`complete.cases` by definition (very efficient since it is just a call to C function)  gives the rows without any  missing value.

Comment: @Arun of course..see my edit(performance explanation) in akrun answer.

Comment: @Arun because the performance is done by akrun and I begin my answer by saying "acrobatic solution" , The OP accpted it I don't know why (reputation baisis) :) but feel free to edit it!

Answer (score 10):

You were very close. Your first try yields a `boolean` vector, which you can use to index the `names` of `df`:

```
contains_any_na = sapply(df, function(x) any(is.na(x)))
names(df)[contains_any_na]
# [1] "b" "c"
```

**Update Jan 14, 2017:** As of R version 3.1.0, `anyNA()` can be used as an alternative to `any(is.na(.))`, and the above code can be simplified to

```
names(df)[sapply(df, anyNA)]
# [1] "b" "c"
```

Answer (score 6):

Try the data.table version:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
names(df)[df[,sapply(.SD, function(x) any(is.na(x))),]]
[1] "b" "c"
```

Microbenchmarking using @akrun's code:

```
set.seed(49)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA,1:200), 1e4*5000, replace=TRUE), ncol=5000))
setDT(df1)


f1 <- function() {contains_any_na = sapply(df1, function(x) any(is.na(x)))
           names(df1)[contains_any_na]}

f2 <- function() {colnames(df1)[!complete.cases(t(df1))] }
f3 <- function() { names(df1)[!!colSums(is.na(df1))] }

f4 <- function() { names(df1)[df1[,sapply(.SD, function(x) any(is.na(x))),]] }

microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), f4(), unit="relative")   
# Unit: relative
#  expr       min        lq    median       uq      max neval
#  f1()  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
#  f2() 10.459124 10.928821 10.955986 9.858967 7.069066   100
#  f3()  3.323144  3.805183  4.159624 3.775549 2.797329   100
#  f4() 10.108998 10.242207 10.121022 9.117067 6.576976   100
```

@agstudy : This solution is similar in speed to  `colnames(df1)[!complete.cases(t(df1))]`.

Comment: this is will be the slowest solution :)

Comment: @rnso I was just joking, my remark was just to say that not because you use data.table you will have the fastest solution. +1  for benchmarking for you and akrun .

Comment: The time taken here is due to `.SD` being a *deep* copy of `df1`. This could be avoided to improve speed in operations without `by`. See [#838](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/838).

Comment: The benchmarking makes this a phenomenal answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
 names(df)[!!colSums(is.na(df))]
 #[1] "b" "c"
```

#### Explanation

```
colSums(is.na(df)) #gives you the number of missing value per each columns
#a b c 
#0 1 1
```

By using `!`, we are creating a logical index

```
!colSums(is.na(df))   #here the value of `0` will be `TRUE` and all other values `>0` FALSE
 #   a     b     c 
 #TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

But, we need to select those columns that have atleast one `NA`, so `!` negate again

```
!!colSums(is.na(df))
#   a     b     c 
#FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

and use this logical index to get the colnames that have at least one `NA`

#### Benchmarks

```
 set.seed(49)
 df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA,1:200), 1e4*5000, replace=TRUE), ncol=5000))

 library(microbenchmark)

 f1 <- function() {contains_any_na = sapply(df1, function(x) any(is.na(x)))
            names(df1)[contains_any_na]}

 f2 <- function() {colnames(df1)[!complete.cases(t(df1))] }
 f3 <- function() { names(df1)[!!colSums(is.na(df1))] }

 microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3(), unit="relative")
 #Unit: relative
 #expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 #f1() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
 #f2() 8.921109 7.289053 6.852122 6.210826 4.889684   100
 #f3() 3.248072 3.105798 2.984453 2.774513 2.599745   100
```

#### EDIT performance explanation:

Maybe surprising  `sapply` based solution  is the winner here because as noted in @flodel comment below , the 2 others solutions created a matrix behind the scene (`t(df)` and `is.na(df)`) create matrix.

Comment: Could you provide some more detail why your solution works, for example that taking the sum of a logical vector yields the number of TRUE values, that `!` means `NOT`. This would make the answer more useful for the OP and other people.

Comment: @Paul Hiemstra Thanks for the comment.  I added some explanation.

Comment: Thanks but why I can't do it with 
names(colSums(is.na(df))>0)?

Comment: but I get:> names(colSums(is.na(df))>0)
[1] "a" "b" "c"

Comment: @GabyP I would say even taht : `!!` is more elegant but `>0` is more readable.

Comment: @akrun amazing benchmarking... I expected that `colSums` is faster than my transpose based solution , but having `sapply` as the fastest this is a real surprise!

Comment: @akrun I guess that `sapply` is the way to go when you want to perform a solution over columns.

Comment: Your two solutions are slower because `t(df)` and `is.na(df)` create matrices.

Answer (score 0):

A simple one liner for this is :

```
colnames(df[,sapply(df, function(x) any(is.na(x)))])
```

Explanation:

```
sapply(df, function(x) any(is.na(x)))
```

returns True/False for columns with atleast 1 NA. `df[,sapply(df, function(x) any(is.na(x)))]` gets the subset of dataframe that has all its columns with atleast 1 NA. And `colnames` gives the names of those columns.