# check empty or na values in columns in R

Tags: mysql, r, dataframe, na

I have a dataframe "d1" from a big MySQL table. I need find there an unused columns (which contains only NA or empty strings).
(see question [Find columns with all missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330138/find-columns-with-all-missing-values) ).

This seems to work fine:

```
allmisscols <- apply(d1,2, function(x)all(is.na(x)));
colswithallmiss <-names(allmisscols[allmisscols>0]);
cat( colswithallmiss,sep="\n");
```

...

```
allmisscols <- apply(d1,2, function(x)all(x==''));
colswithallmiss <-names(allmisscols[allmisscols>0]);
cat( colswithallmiss,sep="\n");
```

...

although the second one gives also "NA" among the column names; i don't understand why.

But when I try to combine them:

```
allmisscols <- apply(d1,2, function(x)all(is.na(x)||x=='') );  
colswithallmiss <-names(allmisscols[allmisscols>0]);    
print("the columns with all values missing");    
print(colswithallmiss);
```

I see a column in result that actually contain a value in my table!

The same gives following:

library(stringr);
sapply(d1, function(x)all(any(is.na(x)||(str_trim(x)==""))))

So my questions are:

1. Why I've got such unexpected results?
2. How can I get the list of column which contains only empty OR N/A values?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
allmisscols <- sapply(dt, function(x) all(is.na(x) | x == '' ))
```

Note: You've used OR as double '||' trying making it a single one. Read this SO post: [Boolean operators && and ||](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558921/boolean-operators-and)